# assign value to database from braintree api call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model, braintree

I am trying to save the customer id which is being created by braintree to my database. i can see that id is being created on braintree and echoed in my terminal but when attempting to allocate to a column within my database it doesn't appear to be saving

```
I, [2016-06-22T23:30:13.267296 #8775]  INFO -- : [Braintree] [22/Jun/2016 13:30:13 UTC] POST /merchants/xxxxx/customers 201
86502732


def create_braintree_customer
    # self.access_token = SecureRandom::hex(9+rand(6)) if access_token.nil?
    result = Braintree::Customer.create(
        :first_name => self.first_name,
        :last_name => self.last_name,
        :email => self.email,
        :phone => self.mobile
    )
    if result.success?
      puts result.customer.id
      self.customer_cim_id = result.customer.id
    else
      p result.errors
    end
  end
```

Comment: Well, you are assigning the value with `self.customer_cim_id = result.customer.id`, but where do you save it to databse? Or your method is called from some before_save callback?

Comment: using after_create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In after_create your model changes will not be saved again. Or use some before_create, before_save and such callback or do update_attribute or update_column (if you don't want to trigger callbacks again).

```
      update_column(:customer_cim_id, result.customer.id)
```

Comment: I am actually trying to execute Braintree calls in before_ methods in order to make sure that I can pass Braintree validations and save all the info in one database call.